# Parsedown, add sub/superscript

Tags: php, regex, markdown, parsedown

I am trying to add sub/superscript to [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/).

[Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/)'s functions seem like a jungle to me. I've been trying to understand it but have been unable to decipher it.

Turning ~text~ into `<sub>text</sub>` seems to be more of a challenge than I'd thought.

Wrapping my head around the structure of his code, is just something that I can't and any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I have looked through the source, tried to find heads and tails in it, but wasn't really able to.

I also tried to learn Regex some months ago, but it seemed quite overwhelming and I ended up postponing it until the coming christmas holiday.

I know it's not just for doing my work, but I really have no idea what to do about it right now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple regex.

Use:

`\~(.*)\~|\^\((.*)\)`

With the substitution <sub>\1\2</sub>

There are two groups in the regex. The key thing here is that the groups won't match at the same time, this is why you can use \1\2

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tS1wD6/2)

Try to understand it and improve if you need something more sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks :)

However I am still having quite the trouble actually integrating it with parsedown.