# Parsedown: sub/superscript

Tags: php, commonmark, parsedown

The current version of [Parsedown 1.8.0-beta-5](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) doesn't have a builtin syntax for sub/superscript. Although [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/) doesn't specify such syntax, several other lightweight markup languages (ex: [Parsedown Extreme](https://github.com/BenjaminHoegh/parsedown-extreme#user-content-superscript--subscript), [Textile](https://txstyle.org/doc/18/subscript-and-superscript-text)) use a syntax similar to the following:

```
in: 19^th^  
out: 19<sup>th</sup>

in: H~2~O  
out: H<sub>2</sub>O
```

**Question**
What steps should be taken in order to modify `Parsedown.php` file and include such syntax?

---

**Note:** This issue has already come up other times ([Parsedown, add sub/superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868146/parsedown-add-sub-superscript)). However, there is still no step-by-step guide explaining what modifications should be done in `Parsedown.php` file in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Append `Superscript` and `Tilde` in `$InlineTypes`:

   ```
   protected $InlineTypes = array(
       '!' => array('Image'),
       '&' => array('SpecialCharacter'),
       '*' => array('Emphasis'),
       ':' => array('Url'),
       '<' => array('UrlTag', 'EmailTag', 'Markup'),
       '[' => array('Link'),
       '_' => array('Emphasis'),
       '`' => array('Code'),
       '~' => array('Tilde'),
       '^' => array('Superscript'),
       '\\' => array('EscapeSequence'),
   );
   ```
2. Define methods `inlineSuperscript`. It should look pretty much like `inlineStrikethrough`:

   ```
   protected function inlineSuperscript($Excerpt)
   {
       if (preg_match('/^\^(.+?)\^/', $Excerpt['text'], $matches))
       {
           return array(
               'extent' => strlen($matches[0]),
               'element' => array(
                   'name' => 'sup',
                   'handler' => array(
                       'function' => 'lineElements',
                       'argument' => $matches[1],
                       'destination' => 'elements',
                   )
               ),
           );
       }
   }
   ```
3. Define methods `inlineTilde` and delete method `inlineStrikethrough`. It should look pretty much like `inlineEmphasis`:

   ```
   protected function inlineTilde($Excerpt)
   {
       if ( ! isset($Excerpt['text'][1]))
       {
           return;
       }

       $marker = $Excerpt['text'][0];

       if ($Excerpt['text'][1] === $marker and preg_match('/^~~(?=\S)(.+?)(?<=\S)~~/', $Excerpt['text'], $matches))
       {
           $emphasis = 'del';
       }
       elseif (preg_match('/^~(?=\S)(.+?)(?<=\S)~/', $Excerpt['text'], $matches))
       {
           $emphasis = 'sub';
       }
       else
       {
           return;
       }

       return array(
           'extent' => strlen($matches[0]),
           'element' => array(
               'name' => $emphasis,
               'handler' => array(
                   'function' => 'lineElements',
                   'argument' => $matches[1],
                   'destination' => 'elements',
               )
           ),
       );
   }
   ```
4. Add the new symbol to `$inlineMarkerList`:

   ```
   protected $inlineMarkerList = '!*_&[:<`~\\^';
   ```